# applying MSDDetector in colab

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, keypoint

I have trouble writing the MSD detector correctly. However, it has no attribute ''create''.

I wrote the following code. But my session crashed for an unknown reason.
msd=cv2.xfeatures2d.MSDDetector()
kps1=msd.detect(I1)
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, you've found a bug here.

there *should* be a ´XXX_create()´ function, but someone forgot to expose it to the python api, by adding a `CV_WRAP` to the [function signature here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/de84cc02a876894a4047ce31f7d9fd179f213e95/modules/xfeatures2d/include/opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp#L374)

(and no, you cannot use the 'ordinary' constructor, it does not produce a valid instance (will segfault, if you call any method on it !!))

- please raise an [issue here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/new/choose)
- if you're able to build from src, try to fix it locally, by changing that line to:

  ```
    CV_WRAP static Ptr<MSDDetector> create(....
  ```